# display charts from firebase data in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, charts, mpandroidchart

[image: this is database structure]

Please help! I am new to Android want to display bar and line chart by using MPCharts form firebase data count. charts should display total count of child for per subjects docs and videos.
every time variable j value is 0 only, not able to set -- NoOfDocs.add(new Entry(count,j));

and here is java code

```
LineChart linechart;
ArrayList NoOfDocs = new ArrayList();
private String [] referenceValues = {"Hindi", "English", "Maths", "Science", "Social Science", "Computer Science", "Art & Craft", "Social Studies", "Physical Education", "Sanskrit"};
private void getDocsData() {
   for (int i=0; i<referenceValues.length;i++) {
       DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(referenceValues[i].toLowerCase()+"/"+AppUtilties.DOCS_PATH);
       dbref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               int j = 0;
               String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
               long count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
               NoOfDocs.add(new Entry(count,j));
               j++;
           }
           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           }
       });}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dashboard");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    ArrayList labels = new ArrayList();
    labels.add("Hindi");
    labels.add("English");
    labels.add("Math");
    labels.add("Science");
    labels.add("Social Science");
    labels.add("Computer Science");
    labels.add("Art");
    labels.add("Social Studies");
    labels.add("Physical Education");
    labels.add("Sanskrit");
    //line chart
    linechart = findViewById(R.id.linechart);
    getDocsData();
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(NoOfDocs, "Number Of Documents");
    LineData lineData = new LineData(labels, lineDataSet);
    linechart.setData(lineData);
    lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    linechart.animateY(2000);
    linechart.getLegend().setWordWrapEnabled(true);
    linechart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);}
```

here is xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/dtitle1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/Documents"
        android:textColor="@color/white_greyish"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/linechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dtitle2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/Videos"
        android:textColor="@color/white_greyish"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
        android:id="@+id/barchart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />






[![database][1]][1]
```